# timeago.js Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

I have a class that holds the time each article is created. I want the time to be *realtime*, which is what **timeago.js** does but my time just stays at **about 1 minute ago** even though it is actually **4 minutes ago**. I have to refresh the page to get the time correctly display.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.post_time').each(function(){
      var tthis = $( this );
      var tt = tthis.html();
      tthis.html($.timeago(tt));
   });
});
```

Comment: Looks correct in first sight - can you provide an url?

Comment: It works only that it doesn't continue as it should. The timing should continue as we have on Facebook time.

Comment: I understood that - but from the code it should work as you aspected - might be, that there is another error or some date formatting issues which cause this - can you provide a fiddle or url to look at?

Comment: I have checked and inspected and found no error. I am yet to have a fiddle account.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vwd4snnd/ working example - and you don't need an account, just save the fiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the result of the timeago method as a string into the element (by using html method), instead of binding the method to the element itself and let it do its work:

**HTML**

```
<div class="post_time" title="2014-11-29T18:13:00Z">2014-11-29</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.post_time').timeago();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwd4snnd/)

Comment: I have like hundred of this class for each article.

Comment: @Yax, and what exactly is your question? You asked why the timeago did not update, I explained why. The way described it will initialize it for all elements with the class .post_time (which has to have a iso-date in title attribute) - updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vwd4snnd/1/